# Correct way to release a COM interface

Tags: com, c++-winrt

We have some legacy software code, which uses COM.  I've noticed that at one place, we perform a queryInterface on an IInspectable pointer, but dont bother calling release.

For ex:

```
void foo(IInspectable* myInterface)
{
    ComPtr<OBJTYPE> pObj;
    auto hr = myInterface->QueryInterface(__uuidof(SomeType),&pObj);
    if (hr != S_OK)
    {
        return hr;
    }
    //some code that uses pObj
}
```

I added Release to the above code like below :

```
auto hr = myInterface->QueryInterface(__uuidof(SomeType),&pObj);
if (hr != S_OK)
{
    return hr;
}
myInterface->Release(); //<-- Is this the correct way to release ?
//some code that uses pObj;
```

But I see that the above code crashes at times in the above function during release.  Is there something wrong in the way I'm releasing the interface ? I can confirm that myInterface is not being used anywhere else in the function after the Release statement.

Apologies for not being able to copy/paste the actual code, but the above code summarizes pretty much the suspect code that I'm debugging.  Basically what I want to know is, in the above scenario, do I need to call Release() ? And is this is the right place/way to call Release() ? Do I need to add any other safety checks in place ?

Comment: [ComPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/comptr-class) seems to be part of the WRL, not C++/WinRT. The `ComPtr` destructor will call `Release` for you. Explicitly calling it will cause a double-delete bug. Since you are passing `myInterface` as a plain pointer, it means that no ownership on the interface is transferred; this is a non-owning pointer. You are only responsible for the `OBJTYPE` interface, and `ComPtr` does that for you.

Comment: ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` is a COM smart-pointer very similar to ATL's ``CComPtr``. You don't need to call ``Release`` explicitly because the smart-pointer does that for you. See [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr). C++/WinRT has a similar ``winrt::com_ptr`` you can use instead of WRL.

Answer (score 2):

In the first `foo` function you should NOT call `myInterface->Release()`. Every call to `Release` should be paired with an adding of a reference. In that function you don't do `myInterface->AddRef`, so if you add `myInterface->Release` then your function will decrement the reference count by one, which does not seem like correct behaviour.

Conceptually, you should call `AddRef` on entry to the function and `Release` on exit of the function. Even though the reference count is "intrusive" in COM, the recommended coding style is to treat each interface pointer like it has its own reference count.

This is normally wrapped up in smart pointer classes. But when working with a function that receives a raw "in" interface pointer, this Add and Release can be "optimized" by just omitting both of those calls in the function, and treating the pointer like an observer pointer.

---

The call to `QueryInterface` will implicitly do `pObj->AddRef()` but this is nothing to do with `myInterface`. When you are finished with `pObj` a `pObj->Release()` should occur -- but this is managed by the `ComPtr` wrapper, you shouldn't add an explicit call.

Comment: *"but this is nothing to do with `myInterface`"* is a bit of a stretch. In the vast majority of cases a call to `QueryInterface` will return a pointer to an interface implemented by the same object as the callee. I believe tear-off interfaces are the only exception. Reference counting is done per object, not per interface.

Comment: @IInspectable see my second paragraph

Comment: I'm not objecting to that, just that the final paragraph steps away from conceptual thinking, and makes a statement that is generally wrong. I'm not sure whether that paragraph should be reworded, or removed entirely. It doesn't add much value as written.